# How to create buffer zone in metres for OSGB1936 layer?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am creating buffer zones in metres on top of UK Ordnance Survey map files that are in OSGB1936 which uses degrees.

How do I draw the buffers in meters?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is in meters. Is it EPSG:27700? if so the units are meters

Comment: There are three OSGB reference systems, one of which, I think gives you degrees rather than metres (EPSG:4277).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataset that is working in degrees, you would ordinarily change the coordinate reference system (CRS) to a flat plane projection system.

You do this through the poject properties menu. Select "CRS" on the left hand side menu. Tick the "Enable on the fly coordinate transformation" and select the correct projection system. In the case of UK ordnance Survey Map Files you would usually select the OSGB 1936 projection, but make sure you use the 27700 reference number (type that into the filter if you can't find it).

Your units should change to metres now.

Comment: OK, I have done this and now the buffer zones are the right size.  Unfortunately they have shifted off the map and are now situated somewhere off the coast of Spain, instead of northern England.

I got the co-ordinates from Google maps, which I think is WGS84.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey make sure in project settings you have enable one the fly projections. If not it wont.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reproject the coordinates to EPSG:27700 too before doing the buffering.

I would suggest to turn On-the-fly-reprojection **OFF** and reproject **all** layers to EPSG:27700 if you want to do correct buffering. Then you can easily see whether the points are located correct or not.